# class item not showing up

Tags: html, css

1for some reason my class item close_full with no show the image. I can't seem to figure out why everything seems to be set up correctly
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2M6KA/2/)

```
#full_image{
width: 339px;
height: 211px;
left: 10px;
position: absolute;
opacity: 1;
z-index: 90000;
}

#full_image img {
left: 10px;    
width: 339px;
height: 211px;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;       
}
#full_image .close_full {
height: 209px;
width: 209px;
position: relative;
background: url('zoom-off.png') no-repeat;
bottom: 5%;
right: -29px;
margin-top: -36px;
cursor: pointer;
z-index: 1;
background-position: right top;   
opacity: 1;
}


<div id="full_image"> <img src="1.jpg"></div>
<span> <a href="#" class="close_full" ></a></span>
```

Comment: @PiLHA: opacity only takes values from 0.0 to 1.0 (http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/opacity)

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/2M6KA/6/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Before you post a question, please first think about what the problem could be. Try to wrap your problem in a small example. And if you cannot find the solution, you can post your example with the question and possible error here on SO. Then we can help you. Your question has almost no information about the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Edit:

you have the "" outside of your div "#full_image"
so I replace

```
#full_image .close_full {...
```

with this

```
.close_full {...
```

and the class .close_full, now is like this:

```
.close_full {
height: 29px;
width: 29px;
position: relative;
background: url('http://tabtimes.com/sites/default/files/Steve%20Wozniak%202.jpg') no-repeat;
bottom: 5%;
right: -29px;
cursor: pointer;
z-index: 9999999;
background-position: right top;
opacity: 1;
display: block;
   }
```

I dont know where you what the close_full link realy must be, but here you have the example:

http://jsfiddle.net/2M6KA/8/

Comment: ok, please correct the jsFiddle, because is not the same that you put at the question